# format date in xslt version 1

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml that looks something like this

```
<book>
  <name>someName</name>
  <date>2014-02-05-05:00</date>
</book>
<book>
  <name>DifferentName</name>
  <date>2014-04-05-05:00</date>
</book>
```

In my xslt i have this schemas

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
```

So when i do

```
<xsl:variable name='myDate' select='date' />
<xsl:value-of select="$myDate" />
```

it works fine, but when i try to do this

```
<xsl:variable name='date' select='impactDate' />
<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date($date, 'MMM dd, yyyy')"/>
```

I get this exception

```
The first argument to the non-static Java function 'formatDate' is not a valid object reference.
```

Does any one know how to fix this exception or is there any other function i can use to do this.

Thank you

Comment: Please include the declaration for the `ms` namespace. Also test what happens if you do `<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date('2014-04-05-05:00', 'MMM dd, yyyy')"/>`.

Comment: ..."urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" is a Microsoft namespace. I don't get how you manage to get a Java error message out of that. How are you calling your XSLT?

Comment: i am calling it in java. Using Transformer class

Comment: when i do this
<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date('2014-04-05-05:00', 'MMM dd, yyyy')"/>
i get same exception

Comment: *"is there any other function i can use to do this."* You could format the date yourself using a named template.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, as it name suggests, ms:anything is a microsoft-specific extension function and is NOT PORTABLE. Bad practice if you can solve the problem any other way, since you're putting yourself in a position where you'll have to go looking for another solution if you ever change XSLT processors.

Better practice would be to use the [EXSLT Date Extensions](http://www.exslt.org/date/). EXSLT is still a set of extension functions and therefore is not guaranteed to be implemented in all XSLT processors -- but many do support most or all of these, and they have the huge advantage that if they're supported at all they will work the same way on all processors that support them.

If you look at the EXSLT page, you'll also find that they show XSLT implementations of many of these functions (as named templates), which can be copied into your stylesheet and used as a *completely* portable solution.

Comment: "*EXSLT is still a set of extension functions and therefore is not guaranteed to be implemented in all XSLT processors -- but many do support most or all of these*" I don't know of *any* processor that supports the EXSLT date:format-date() function.

Comment: Granted; I'm pointing in a general preferred direction. But as I said, whether the extension function is available as a function or not, there _is_ [the EXSLT implementation of this operation as an XSLT template](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/format-date/date.format-date.template.xsl). EXSLT should always be the first place to look.

Comment: (If you're going to go nonstandardized, and you're Java-based, the right answer rather than tying yourself to Microsoft is to plug in your own extension function -- or, as some processors will permit, to invoke the Java operation.)

Comment: I can write my own in less time than it takes me to read theirs... Not to mention that theirs probably won't work with the OP's non-standard input.

Comment: You can. I could. The OP presumably couldn't, given the question they were asking. De gustibus.

Comment: I am afraid you have missed my point: I was not talking about my advantages; I was talking about my shortcomings. *I* cannot absorb that amount of code in a reasonable time - certainly not in a time reasonable for such task as the one presented here. Pointing the OP to it as a solution is not doing them any favors. The only way they can benefit from it is by way of voodoo programming (which probably won't work anyway for the reason already mentioned). So no, this is not a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

[ms:format-date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256099%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects a dateTime string that has to be formatted like this: 2000-02-16T15:56:00

try getting it in the correct format first, something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="date" select="concat(substring(date,1,10),'T',substring(date,12),':00')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date($date, 'MMM dd, yyyy')"/>
```

Edit: Just saw you're using java for the transformation, for the ms:* functions to work I think you will have to use MSXML or .Net to do your transformation